# set_alpha() not working when using a png image as game over surface

Tags: python, image, pygame, photoshop

When the game is over, I want to put an image above it. But I don't want it to override the game over surface, so I hope I can set the transparency of the png image after i load and `convert_alpha()`. But it isn't working after I use `set_alpha(0)`.

What I can think of the problem are:

1. my png image doesn't have alpha channel, so I checked it in my photoshop. It is rgb, not rgba, so how can I add alpha channel for it which means convert rgb to rgba.

(Note: I can change the transparency of the image in photoshop and use it in my pygame, it works but i wanna i can change the degree of transparency in my program anytime, not just have to use photoshop)

2. my pygame methods using wrong

png image:

[image]

The result I want is here:

[image]

(please ignore the Chinese, they are just another two images)):

Code is:

```
img_bg = pygame.image.load('./ui/background.png').convert_alpha()
img_bg.set_alpha(0)
screen.blit(img_bg, (0, 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

[`set_alpha`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_alpha) doesn't work with surfaces that use per pixel alpha, so use the `convert` method instead of `convert_alpha`. I changed the value to `70`, since `0` would make the image fully transparent.

```
img_bg = pygame.image.load('./ui/background.png').convert()
img_bg.set_alpha(70)
```

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, it's also possible to set the transparency of per pixel alpha surfaces, but that's more complicated. I think I've already answered that elsewhere.